# getting contacts by phone numbers

Tags: java, android, performance, android-contacts

Am looking for a way to select contacts by providing some phone numbers, for example i'd like to select all contacts that has any of this phone numbers (+1234567890) or (+1234567889).

Since contact phone numbers can be stored in different formats, i can't use this method

```
contentResolver.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER + " in (?)", new String[]{"(+1234567890,+1234567889"}, null);
```

i found a way that allows me to search contacts by number, but only providing one number, not a list, like this:

```
 Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(number));
    contentResolver.query(uri,null,
            null,
            null, null);
```

Is there any way to provide this query a list of numbers instead ?

I understand that i can select all contacts and then loop through them to filter them, but its slow and not recommended.

Any suggestion will be appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: If you're worried about the different formats, as you should be, you might want to load the entire list, perform regex on all the phone numbers, and then look for your number that way. The reason for this is because SQLite doesn't support regex in queries, which is unfortunate.

Comment: @tambykojak but that causes performance issues which what i was trying to avoid.

Comment: I wouldn't go as far as to say it causes performance issues. It's not the ideal scenario, but after I looked at the variety of formats in my contacts list and since regex isn't supported, that's the first solution that came to my head.

Comment: @tambykojak i guess if there's no other methods then yes that should be the solution to use.